# Ошибка при попытке удалить стандартные классы меню wordpress фильтром nav_menu_css_class

Tags: wordpress

В общем нужно удалить стандартные классы меню, классы успешно удалились, но вордпресс выводит ошибку. Код вроде правильный, не могу понять в чем проблема.

**Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\OpenServer\domains\wplavr\wp-includes\class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 158**

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', function($classes, $menu_item, $args, $depth){
    
$classes = '';
return $classes;

}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: Потому что ожидается что `$classes` будет массивом, так как изначально это массив. Замените на `$classes = [];`

Comment: Точно.. Спасибо большое)